# Uplodify onSelect event problem!

Tags: jquery, uploadify, onselect

I need to validate selected file in onSelect event and according to that modify content of Uplodify element for example change to error style and hide progress and add some description in percentage div!

problem is that it not find anything about Uplodify content in onSelect event!!!

there is any solution for this problem?

my code is here :

```
var $max_file_size = 1024000;
var $arr_allow_extention = ['.jpg', '.gif', '.png'];
//console.log($arr_allow_extention);
$($idSelector).uploadify({
    'uploader'  : $project_public_path + '/share/library/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : $project_public_path + '/share/library/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : $project_public_path + '/share/library/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : $project_public_path + '/uploaded_resource/bug',
    'sizeLimit' : $max_file_size, // 10 MB
    'auto'      : false,
    'buttonText'  : ' Browse ',
    'fileExt'     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
    'fileDesc'    : 'Web Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG)',
    'removeCompleted' : false,

      'onSelect'    : function(event, ID, fileObj) {
        var $has_error = false;
        var $error_msg = '';

        $( $idSelector ).removeAttr('title').removeClass();
        $( $idSelector ).parent().find('.check-ok, .check-error').remove();

        if (fileObj.size >= $max_file_size) {
            //console.log( 'size is over!' ); 
            $has_error = true;
            $error_msg += 'Maximum file size reached!';
        }

        if ( $.inArray(fileObj.type, $arr_allow_extention) ) {
            $has_error = true;
            $error_msg += 'Extention not allowed';

            $($idSelector + ID).find('.percentage').text(" - " + $error_msg + " Error");
            $($idSelector + ID).find('.uploadifyProgress').hide();
            $($idSelector + ID).addClass('uploadifyError');
        }

        if ( $has_error ) {
            $('#img-upload-btn').remove();
            $($idSelector).text('');
            $( $idSelector ).addClass('error');
            $( $idSelector ).after( "<span class=\"check-error\" title=\"" + $error_msg + "\"></span>" );
        } else {
            $('#imgQueue').before( "<span id=\"img-upload-btn\" title=\"Press to upload\" class=\"button\"><img src=\"" + $project_public_path + "/share/library/uploadify/upload-btn.jpg\" style=\"display:none;\" /></span>" );

            $('#img-upload-btn').click(function(){
                //console.log( ID );
                $($idSelector).uploadifyUpload( ID );
            });
            $( $idSelector ).after( "<span class='check-ok'></span>" );
        }

    }       
});
```

these line of code not work :
               $($idSelector + ID).find('.percentage').text(" - " + $error_msg + " Error");
                $($idSelector + ID).find('.uploadifyProgress').hide();
                $($idSelector + ID).addClass('uploadifyError');

there is any solution?

Comment: All codes are in a function and I send $idSelector as a param to that function, it can be a jQuery selector like '#uploadBtn'

Comment: have you checked in the firebug are there any errors/

Comment: Yes I check,there is no error! just it not know aboout of elements!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your problem?

Comment: undortunately not yet !